# Can we store/get Client Side Persistent data using Prototype.js

Tags: prototypejs

Please comment on this How can we store Client Side Persistent data using Prototype.js?
For Ex.:-In Curl Programming language we can set the data as key-value pair in persistent storage and get through the key.

Regards,
Mannusanghi

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to access the persistent storage facility of the browser (or browser plugin) in prototype.js. You will have to look for another library in addition to prototype.

I have no experience with it, but the first hit on Google is [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557), which looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're not storing a ton of data, couldn't you just use cookies to store the key/value pairs?

here is an article on implementing cookies using prototype

http://www.lalit.org/lab/jsoncookies

you can also create, delete, and read cookies using pure js if u want

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

The prototype library focuses on DOM manipulation/additions and selection. It's best for 'view' code, and doesn't have a facility to access browser storage by-itself, but there is no reason why you cannot use it in conjunction with other libraries.

You can [read more about client-side storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) from the W3C

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Rgrove who developed this library:
http://github.com/rgrove/storage-lite

It covers all the possible use cases for storing persistent data using local storage and not cookies. This library uses YUI but it is easy to make it work with prototype.js: the core remains exactly the same. Compatible with IE6+, Firefox 2+, Safari 3.1+, Chrome 4+, and Opera 10.5+ without any further installation.